# Is it possible to change the bg color with a textbox input in tkinter,python?

Tags: python, tkinter, textbox

*I know the code isn't complete but I'm new to coding and Tkinter and couldn't find any good sources around?*

```
from tkinter import*
class textbox:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.s =StringVar
        self.s.set(0)
        WD=17
    f1=frame(parent)
    self.frame = frame(f1,parent, width=300, height =300, bg="deeppink")
    self.frame.grid(row=1,colimnspan = 3)
    self.label(f1,text= "Change Colour", bg ="gray", wraplength=100, width=WD, anchor=CENTER)
    self.entry=Entry(f1,width=15, command = self.bg_colour)
    self.label.pack(side=LEFT)
    self.entry.pack(fill= Y, expand = TRUE)

def bg_colour(self):
        self.frame.configure(bg = self.entry)

if __name__=="__main__":
        root=Tk()
        Frame=textbox(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A `Entry` widget does not have a `command=` option. You need to `.bind(...` or a `Button` widget. Furthermore you have a indentation error, `def bg_colour(self):` belongs not to `class textbox`. Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I might not be understanding your question correctly, are you trying to change the background color of the textbox right away, or when a button is pressed or an event happens?